# how to get detailed smoke without increasing resolution divisions

Tags: physics, smoke-simulation, resolution

i am making a smoke simulation , but the smoke isn't detailed so i increased the resolution divisions , bu then after making it 200 , the device started hanging , i have a i5 8gen hp 4gb ram laptop , i know the specs are not that high but is there a way to increase the resolution so that there is enough detail without freezing , also i cannot see any high resolution tab which is there in one of the tutorials in the physics tab